# Adding eventlistener with async javascript function

Tags: javascript, setinterval, addeventlistener, vertical-scrolling

Hi I was trying to set an event handler on an html div only after a function is executed.
I would like to add an event handler to the div "chatContainer" using the function ff that runs after half a second.

```js
function ff(){
    setTimeout(
    function () {
     document.getElementById("chatContainer").addEventListener("scroll",console.log("testing"))
    },0)}
setTimeout(ff(),500)
```

```html
<div id="chatContainer">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum hendrerit at nisi a vehicula. Phasellus dictum, lectus in finibus ultricies, erat ante tincidunt ligula, eu euismod nisi massa sed tortor. Ut molestie ullamcorper hendrerit. Proin ut eros cursus, egestas felis eget, eleifend massa. Fusce id sagittis nisl, ut scelerisque neque. Sed in ultrices ipsum. Pellentesque egestas nibh ut risus vehicula scelerisque. Sed mollis eros lectus, at convallis leo interdum egestas. Curabitur eu quam eu tortor hendrerit lacinia id tempus neque. Ut quis tempor enim.

Praesent felis est, faucibus nec accumsan vitae, condimentum in lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin eros metus, egestas quis sem sit amet, viverra viverra turpis. Vestibulum volutpat non lectus vitae sollicitudin. Donec pharetra tempor auctor. Nunc lacinia id ex nec imperdiet. Curabitur sagittis lacinia faucibus.

Ut convallis gravida erat eget eleifend. Pellentesque eu ipsum non nisi laoreet efficitur. Vivamus rhoncus metus vitae sem congue consequat. Aliquam rutrum, nisi lacinia tempus feugiat, est metus finibus odio, non vulputate velit velit nec ex. Nunc tincidunt ex tempus neque aliquam viverra. Quisque vel ullamcorper urna, id commodo nisi. Duis tempus sapien id mollis posuere. Vestibulum vitae metus gravida, lobortis sem vitae, venenatis massa. Vestibulum vel turpis tempor, egestas libero feugiat, blandit ex. Aliquam commodo non sapien interdum faucibus. Ut sagittis imperdiet ultricies. Aenean faucibus vitae massa quis ultricies. Aliquam id arcu viverra, tristique leo eget, congue urna. Morbi sit amet dui at sem molestie rutrum.
Aenean non quam a dui ullamcorper tincidunt. Quisque quis dui viverra, ullamcorper lectus et, varius sapien. Nunc a enim non quam interdum lobortis. Integer vehicula id lectus quis scelerisque. Pellentesque eros ipsum, maximus sed massa ornare, scelerisque scelerisque orci. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Vivamus magna eros, suscipit dapibus semper et, lobortis at enim. Suspendisse ac pharetra massa. Sed ut ex odio. Nullam posuere, diam non condimentum aliquam, libero neque venenatis purus, nec aliquam risus elit dignissim sem. Quisque sagittis suscipit nibh vel pretium. Integer mollis congue purus id sodales. Nunc sollicitudin dui id euismod vestibulum. Proin dignissim nunc lacus, sit amet imperdiet erat suscipit in. Donec ipsum tellus, porta eu turpis ut, aliquet maximus tortor. Sed vel pharetra ipsum.

In neque turpis, egestas id vulputate in, placerat a nunc. Integer aliquam, augue ac dapibus ultrices, velit dolor sollicitudin nisl, ut feugiat velit mi quis urna. Nulla facilisi. Sed lacinia, ipsum et euismod condimentum, urna elit condimentum purus, sed lobortis velit ipsum quis lectus. Cras rutrum diam orci, ac ultrices leo eleifend quis. Donec ornare massa vel turpis tempor mollis. Sed pharetra viverra massa, nec tincidunt elit elementum at. Maecenas ornare ex vitae magna accumsan, ut commodo arcu accumsan. Phasellus eu tempus lorem. Phasellus a consequat nibh, sed consectetur sem. Aenean porta mollis velit, sit amet fermentum dui suscipit quis. Integer iaculis nec augue id congue. Praesent porttitor feugiat urna.
</div>
```

When I run the code however the event listener doesn't seems to work and testing is only logged once after running the function ff.
Does anyone know a solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `setTimeout(ff(),500)` -> `setTimeout(ff,500)` and `.addEventListener("scroll",console.log("testing"))` -> `.addEventListener("scroll",() => console.log("testing"))`

Comment: Thanks VLAZ works like a sharm if you post this answer I'll approve it and vote you up.